# How to use Angular Predicate interface with logical operators ( AND/OR )?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, predicate

I am trying to write a dynamic search functionality on basis of [Angular Predicate](https://angular.io/api/core/Predicate#:%7E:text=Predicatelink&text=A%20boolean%2Dvalued%20function%20over,value%27s%20position%20in%20an%20array.) interface. I am able to run it for single criteria. There are multiple criteria's to which the predicates will be formed and compared with `&&` and `||` operators.
I am not sure if its possible with angular Predicates but its possible with Java 8 Predicates.

The object is form a predicate like `p => this.getGeneralPredicate(p, c => p.code, criteria) && this.getGlobalPredicate(p, c => p.code, criteria) || this.getOtherPredicate(p, c => p.code, criteria)`

```
var compositePredicates: Predicate<Items> = null;
advanceSearchRequest.query.forEach(criteria => {
var predicate = this.getPredicate(criteria);
  if (compositePredicates == null) {
    compositePredicates = predicate;
});
```

Dynamically preparing predicates

```
getPredicate(criteria): Predicate<Items> {
  switch (criteria.category) {
    case "General":
      return p => this.getGeneralPredicate(p, c => p.code, criteria)
      break;
    case "Global":
      return p => this.getGlobalPredicate(p, c => p.code, criteria)
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  return;
}
```

Filtering contents

```
var data = [];
Object.values([cursor.value])
  .filter(compositePredicates)
  .map(filteredData => {
     data.push(filteredData);
});
```